# why is copy_file_range() undefined with 4.15 Linux kernel?

Tags: linux, system-calls

The manpage for `copy_file_range()` at

https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/copy_file_range.2.html

says:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <unistd.h>

ssize_t copy_file_range(
```

(...)

```
The copy_file_range() system call first appeared in Linux 4.5
```

but when I try to compile the user sample code that contains the above, I get

`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘copy_file_range’`(...)

`In function ‘main':`

(...)`undefined reference to ‘copy_file_range'`

and I have Linux 4.15 :

```
$uname -r
4.15.0-142-generic
```

NOTE:  I don't want to use any user-mode version which may or may not be present in glibc.  I want to use the kernel version which should be available according to the manpage and also to all the Googling I could find.  I want to know why is it not available - is the documentation completely wrong? Is it missing some crucial requirement for compilation? Am I completely not understanding something basic?

Full data which I think is irrelevant:

Full sample code `foobar.c` from the documentation:

```
   #define _GNU_SOURCE
   #include <fcntl.h>
   #include <stdio.h>
   #include <stdlib.h>
   #include <sys/stat.h>
   #include <unistd.h>

   int
   main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
       int fd_in, fd_out;
       struct stat stat;
       off64_t len, ret;

       if (argc != 3) {
           fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s <source> <destination>\n", argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       fd_in = open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);
       if (fd_in == -1) {
           perror("open (argv[1])");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       if (fstat(fd_in, &stat) == -1) {
           perror("fstat");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       len = stat.st_size;

       fd_out = open(argv[2], O_CREAT | O_WRONLY | O_TRUNC, 0644);
       if (fd_out == -1) {
           perror("open (argv[2])");
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }

       do {
           ret = copy_file_range(fd_in, NULL, fd_out, NULL, len, 0);
           if (ret == -1) {
               perror("copy_file_range");
               exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
           }

           len -= ret;
       } while (len > 0 && ret > 0);

       close(fd_in);
       close(fd_out);
       exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
   }
```

Full errors:

```
$ gcc foobar.c
foobar.c: In function ‘main’:
foobar.c:40:19: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘copy_file_range’; did you mean ‘sync_file_range’? [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
   40 |             ret = copy_file_range(fd_in, NULL, fd_out, NULL, len, 0);
      |                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                   sync_file_range
/tmp/ccfnzueg.o: In function `main':
foobar.c:(.text+0x127): undefined reference to `copy_file_range'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Comment: What glibc version are you using? `I get` Please post full error verbatim messages with line numbers and please add your compile command. `for copy_file_range() at` Do you have `man copy_file_range` available locally?

Comment: If your version of glibc is too old, it's not going to have the function.

Comment: @Shawn yes I know, that is _not_ my problem

Comment: Then what's the question? Update to a version of glibc that supports it, or maybe invoke the syscall directly with `syscall(2)`. That's a minor pain though.

Comment: @Shawn the question is as in the title "why is copy_file_range() undefined with 4.15 Linux kernel?"

Comment: And the answer which you said you already knew is that your glibc version is too old to have support for it.

Comment: @KamilCukwhy should it matter what glibc I have (I have an older one without a user-space version for copy_file_range). I don't want to use the user-space version in glibc. The whole point of copy_file_range() is that it is a kernel functionality. I only included the relevant information to make it easiest for the reader, but OK if you want I will give you all the irrelevant information. Finally, copy_file_range is not a user command, so there is no point about "local manpage".   I just want to know, why is copy_file_range not defined when the documentation says it should.

Comment: @Shawn the question says "with 4.15 kernel", it's about the syscall, not about what is or is not in glibc.  Let me make it more explicit.

Comment: I'm starting to understand. You don't understand how the relevant bits work. For each syscall (Well, most of them; some don't have any support) there's a wrapper function in glibc that will invoke the kernel system call for you. If your version of glibc doesn't have a wrapper for the desired syscall, you can't use it unless you invoke it directly with `syscall(2)`, because the function doesn't exist.

Comment: This is why things like asking you to mention what glibc version you're using is important.

Comment: @Shawn OK thank you, please bear with me...   I know about syscall() and all that, that it has to be used if there is no wrapper etc.  But the thing is, the documentation (that I quote) explicitly says that glibc may have, not a wrapper, but a user-space implementation.  I guess it is very misleading...

Comment: @Shawn it says "The copy_file_range() system call first appeared in Linux 4.5,
       but glibc 2.27 provides a user-space emulation when it is not
       available.".  I mean, according to you, this is bonkers?

Comment: The logic in the function looks something like `if running_kernel_version < 4.5 then emulate_cfr() else invoke_syscall_for_cfr()`

Comment: note also that not all file systems support the call.

Comment: @Shawn yes thank you, I appreciate.  I still think the documentation for copy_file_range() (available on man7 and elsewhere) is totally misleading.